# ExpressionEngine CMS 3.4.4 - Why am I unable to edit from the structure page?

Tags: structure

[image]

Our digital agency said that we need some special plug in...I'm not sure I believe that.  Any thoughts why I wouldn't be able to edit the site from here?

Comment: What do you mean by edit the site? As in, you cannot click on any of those links (e.g. "Our Culture") and edit that page?

Answer (score 0):

Might be you haven't got sufficient rights in the member group you are in

Comment: I am the admin, they told me "it's not possible with this version of EE", I have worked on previous versions and thought that was just part of what makes EE to user friendly...I think they did a bad build, but I could be wrong

Comment: can't think of what might be wrong. Maybe @tomjaeger can help you out. Post this issue on the EE slack channel!